# output from tinyMCE has linebreaks or newlines that are causing issues with my php code

Tags: php, tinymce, newline

I am setting up tinyMCE to work with my php blog.  I get values from tinyMCE and store them in mysql server.  When I get these values back out however tinyMCE stores line breaks is causing an issue with my code.

Here is an example of what tinyMCE produces:

```
<p>test with line break</p>
<p><img src="../images/blogpics/jumping_penguin.jpg" alt="" width="80" height="64" /></p>
```

Now if I enter that same text in by typing directly into the mysql server like this:

```
<p>test with line break </p><p><img src="../images/blogpics/jumping_penguin.jpg" alt="" width="80" height="64" /></p>
```

It works fine.  What is tinyMCE doing that is causing me errors and how can I get around it?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: as far as html goes they are the same thing. i suspect you process the output again after  tinyMCE has done its thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding the following to the tinymce.init call

> forced_root_block: false,